Installing lunarvim from script with the questions answered
On their website, you're asked to install their program via a script instead of downloading it via a package repository like most regular apps do.
LV_BRANCH='release-1.4/neovim-0.9' bash <(curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/LunarVim/LunarVim/release-1.4/neovim-0.9/utils/installer/install.sh)

The installation process, but I want to create a script where the questions are answered.
How would one write a command that deals with the questions automatically?


How would one write a command that deals with the questions automatically?

That depends on the script whose questions you answer; no general rule exists. In your case, the easiest way would be not to blindly trust the installation script, as it doesn't seem to be doing what you want anyways, but to download and modify it the way you need it. There's a function confirm defined in there, and you can just replace the handful of places it's being called with your decision.

This is the official installation method for lunarvim. I'm not going to replace their installation script. I want a command that answers to their script.

yes, then go into that script and learn what it does. It's not a "magical thing" that you shall not touch, but one that does a few simple things. A script that answers the questions is as complicated to write as a script that just does what it should without asking you.

But even if you need to know what your own "answering script" (by the way, the expect program allows for such scripts to be written), you will want to read the original script that you're answering to. Note that I think it's a bad idea to supplement a verbatim installer script with an "answering script", when you could just as well add a "use defaults" switch to the original script, and probably would have that upstreamed by the end of the day. It's not like these projects are slow to absorb helpful changes.

You're right. I'll okay this answer then, because it seems like I'll need to bring this to the lunarvim team.

@Folaht you don't need to "bring this to the lunarvim team": You're not a paying customer of some company. As I said now (three times!) instead of writing your own complicated answering script, just add an option to the existing script (which is much, much easier!) that circumvents you even being asked. Then, take that, make it a pull request, so that the next person, or you on the next machine, can just use the standard installer that way. It's both easier, more helpful, and it will also continue to work when they change anything about the installer.

That sounds like a couple of weeks of work, only to see it rejected. I'll do that once I have my project finished.

again, you can tell yourself that, or do the literal 8 lines of code changes and make a PR. That's about 10 minutes of work? In any way, way less than writing a script that parses questions being asked and replies, and breaks the next morning when the project asks a new question in the installer script.

I would need a new IDE for that, set up that IDE, fork their github project, understand their code, fail a million ways, figure out how to do a PR in the first place, only to be told that they have no intention of doing it that way due to reason X or Y and that it doesn't work on their machine, despite it working on mine.

stop bullshitting yourself. You don't have to use an IDE to edit a single python file; you can even do a PR directly on github by clicking on "edit this file". Yes, you can do it in your bad, fragile way, if you want to. The point of upstreaming is that someone else takes care of your code once it works. But let this long-term FOSS developer and maintainer tell you that you're really automating at the wrong end. The time you spent complaining here would have sufficed for you to do all the things you complain about in your previous comment. I'll stop reacting to this level of argumentation now.

That's really nice that you've had easy goings with PRs. Your experience has not been the same as mine.

again, time spent complaining here could have spent getting help doing that. You are clearly not trying to cooperatively solve this. Have a nice day!

Talking to the Lunarvim team I discovered that Lunarvim discontinued their project. You too, have a nice day.
